How to convert Chrome cookies "expiration_time" to a readable date / time?
On Google Chrome's cookies, the timestamp values are like this :
1765064691
What calculation i need to do in order to convert this integer, to a human readable date / time ?

// Chrome expiration_time as unix timestamp
let timestamp = 1765064691;

// Convert to milliseconds
let readableDate = new Date(timestamp * 1000);

// Format date and time
console.log("UTC:", readableDate.toUTCString()); // UTC time
console.log("Lokal:", readableDate.toLocaleString()); // locale time

And next time, please try to do some researches on your own. This question is so simple it makes me think that you haven't even tried ;)
